# perl: how to pass more than one value to a system command?

Tags: perl

in dos, i would run the following command

```
simread31 file.sim
```

and the program would ask me for 9 inputs.

Now, i'd like to do it in perl. I know i can combine `echo` with `system` in order for one input, but how to do it for more than one?

many thanks

Answer (score 3):

The reason you're having trouble doing this with `system()` is that it's the wrong tool for the job.  If you `open(my $fh, '|-', 'simread31', 'file.sim')` you'll be able to `print` or `say` your input to the child program's STDIN.

I'm not at my machine right now so that syntax is from memory.  `perldoc perlopen` should provide more detail.

**Windows**

As Windows does not implement the list form of the piped open, you should use something like this:
`open(my $fh, '|-', "simread3.exe $sim_file")`

Piping input directly from Perl will often be more efficient than opening, writing, closing, piping via `system()`, and then cleaning up an external file.

Comment: Hello, many thanks for your answer. Because I am working on a Windows machine, I cannot use the list for `open`.
I have succeeded with system and an auxiliary file prepared some steps earlier:
`system ( "simread3.exe $sim_file <simread3_input.txt" ) ;`